# What is the difference between using a sql-command cmdlet and restore cmdlet?

Tags: sql, powershell

I'm looking at using a Powershell script to automate a Restore process on my SQL Server 2008 instance, and I'm seeing that there's two separate ways of doing it:

- Use a invoke-sqlcmd cmdlet
- Load Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore and use the focused restore method in there

I've read through the TechNet documentation, but I think my question might be too basic to be covered in there. With code that is as simple as the following, and will be static (iterating maybe the name of the backup to coincide with the date it's taken):

```
RESTORE DATABASE Loadtest
    FROM DISK = 'D:\databases\LoadTest_09_09_2013.bak'
    WITH REPLACE
GO
```

Why would I use anything but the simple invoke-sqlcmd? It seems like the script will end up being more complicated using the direct restore class. Do I gain any sort of performance increases using the restore?

Note that I do have SQL Management Studio installed on this workstation, and the complete powershell script is going to eventually do some other test environment maintenance (clearing caches, etc.).

Comment: One of the reasons I like using SMO instead of invoke-sqlcmd is the KillAllProcesses() method in SMO.  With that I don’t have to even check if there are connections to the database getting restored.  But since this is just my reason I won’t make this an answer.  I’m interested in seeing what others have to say.

Comment: That's an interesting thing to note. I might end up going the same route, although you can do the same thing just within the SQL query using a fancy version of 'Kill'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke-SqlCmd is a horrible hack.

- If you want to run a command from a text file, that filepath cannot have spaces
- If something bad happens you only get a vague text message.
- It actually calls out to run the sqlcmd executable, creating yet another level of indirection
- GO (batching) is not supported at all

SMO Advantages:

- Errors are returned in a full ErrorRecord with Exception/InnerException chain so you can actually diagnose things
- It uses Powershell objects natively, so you aren't just throwing around strings that may or may not require escaping
- SQL commands can be executed directly using native objects, allowing richer debugging and error recovery